# Prevent ng-template from being rendered in transclusion

Tags: angular, transclusion

When we use a `ng-template` to create a predefined template the content is rendered before usage.

This is a problem when we have elements like autocomplete that call remote apis to fetch data.

I would like to prevent this and render the template content only when needed.

Context: I have a table component with advacned filter that is opened when the user clicks in the advanced filter button. I do not want the filter to be rendered until the user wants it to do so.

Edit: My problem is not waiting the data to arrives. My problem is that I do not want to render the autocomplete until the user open the table advanced filter. My table is a component and uses transclusion to get the filter. So, I do not want to use IFs in the component that uses the table but in the table itself that controls when the filter shhould be displayed.

EDIT: It was a miss understanding by my part. Actually the content is not rendered on viewInit. The render was hapening in my table advance filter that was being mounted in hidden mode. Placing one *ngIf in my `ngTemplateOutlet` fixed the problem.

#### list-advanced-filter.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="opened"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{form: form}"
></ng-container>
```

Comment: did you try adding an *ngIf with a condition that only shows the template after your data has loaded?  e.g. <ng-template *ngIf="isDataLoaded"></ng-template>.  If it doesn't work with ng-template, try with ng-container

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if I use it for transclusion (use the template as `ng-content` in another componente) I cannot control it from the parent component so I cannot use this logic to control when the template should be displayed or note.

Comment: `ngTemplateOutlet` Check this out: https://medium.com/michalcafe/angulars-content-projection-trap-and-why-you-should-consider-using-template-outlet-instead-cc3c4cad87c9

Comment: @jcroll I think this approach works but the dev need to create two templates for populate the advanced filter and that is something that I want to avoid. But it is for sure one solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Parent component.ts

```
{
public showTemplate:boolean;

public setShowTemplate(event){
this.showTemplate = event;
}
```

parent.html

```
<some-component *ngIf="showTemplate" (childShowTemplate)="setShowTemplate($event)"></some-component>
```

some-component.ts{

```
@Output()
childShowTemplate = new EventEmitter();

 ngOnInit(){ // or any method you want like ngOnChanges or whatever
  if(someCondition){
     this.childShowTemplate.emit(true);
  }else{
    this.childShowTemplate.emit(false);
  }
 }
}
```

By this way the child can decide if it wants to be rendered or not.

Or you can create a service method to handle this situation...

Comment: Kostas, that is what I'm trying to avoid. I do not think the logic of showing or not the advanced filter should be placed in the parent component. I want the logic in the table component. The parent only tell the table what is the advanced filter template and the table displays it when the user click in advanced filter button... But it is for sure one way to solve it! Thanks a lot!